# How do I test the load time of my application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, performance, cocoa-touch

I would like to benchmark the load time of my application but am not sure how to do this. I could start by inserting a couple of `NSLog`s and comparing the time stamps. But where should I place these?

Should I place the second log in my root view controller's `viewDidAppear` since this is the first time the application is available to the user? And what about the first log? I was considering applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: but the name suggests this is a little late.

Any references to tutorials, instruments, or anything else would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the watchdog is concerned, "launch time" is the time it takes from `main` being called until `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` returns YES. If this time is too long, your app gets killed with the "bad food" exception.

The parts of the code that are under your control and affect the user begin at `application:didFinish...` (`willFinish` in iOS6) and end, as you say, on viewDidAppear of your first view controller. Logging at the start of these methods would be fine.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) is a reference for the stages of an application's launch and life cycle.

Answer (score 3):

You could log the launch time of the first frame this way:

```
int main(int argcv, char *argv[])
{
    startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
}

-(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching(UIApplication *)app {
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     NSLog(@"Launched in %f sec", CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime);

}
```

If you have access to the `2012 WWDC` videos - I recommend taking the excellent video session `235` on ios App performance & responsiveness. They have a section on how to mesure loading time.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
//[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"]
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
NSLog(@"Date%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
[dateFormatter release];
```

the begin time minus the end time then you get the load time